# Function defined as a series using rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence of rational numbers, define
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n |x-r_n|^{1/2}}$$
Let $a<b$ then $f\in L^1(a,b)$ and $f\notin L^2(a,b)$

The first part seems to work out. We split the sum $\sum_{n:|r_n|<A}+\sum_{n:|r_n|\geq A}$ and bound $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{|x-r_n|^{1/2}}$ in each case. How to deal with the second part of the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Pick an $n$ so that $a < r_n < b$. Then $f(x) \geqslant \,?$

Comment: Ok, thanks... $|f(x)|^2 \geq |x-r_n|^{-1}$ then $\int_a^b |x-r_n|^{-1} = \infty$

Comment: There's the $2^{-n}$ factor. Of course $(2^{-n})^2 \cdot \infty$ is still $\infty$.